# Docker official registry url

Tags: docker

I need the docker official registry url. I googled 30min + went to the actual hub.docker.com site, but couldn't find it. It seems it is nowhere defined. Is it the: https://hub.docker.com? Or something else?

There was some old question related to this, but it is probably outdated for now.

I mean the docker registry where you pull images by default after installing docker. (And without logging in to any other registry)

Comment: `docker info | grep -i registry`

Answer (score 6):

```
docker info | grep -i registry
```

> Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/

I had the same issue while trying to use it with AWS ECS.